# CSS MIME mismatch in browser using Angular and Deno

Tags: angular, deno

I'm setting up an Angular-Deno stack proof of concept. For Angular app generation `@angular/cli` version 9.1.9 is used. After the app was generated, I create a production build with `npm run build -- --prod` and the output is in the `dist` folder of the application.

The deno server code is following:

```
import { Application } from "https://deno.land/x/abc@v1.0.0-rc8/mod.ts";

const app = new Application();

app.static("/", "./client/dist/client");
app.file("/", "./client/dist/client/index.html");
app.start({ port: 8080 });
```

The paths are correct, the built Angular app is in `./client/dist/client`.

When I start the server with `deno run --allow-net --allow-read .\server.ts` command and navigate to `http://localhost:8080/ url in the browser the Angular application is downloaded. This is working fine.

However, there is a warning on the browser console:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain
```

[image]

I checked the generated `index.html` of the Angular app, and the CSS reference looks following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.09e2c710755c8867a460.css"></head>
```

If I change the above `<link>` to

```
<link type="text/css" href="styles.09e2c710755c8867a460.css"></head>
```

then it is working fine, the warning disappears from the browser console.

Is there a way to generate the `index.html` of the Angular app so that it contains the `<link>` entry of the second way above?
Or is there a configuration in deno request pipeline that can handle the originally generated `<link>` entry of the Angular app and set the CSS MIME correctly?

I would like to avoid using a custom post-build script to change the `<link>` entry of the generated html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `link` tag is correct but the `abc` framework is not setting the right `Content-Type` header for `css` files, in fact `static` middleware does not set `Content-Type` at all for any file type.

To fix it, you can set the `Content-Type` yourself using a middleware, or use a framework that has that functionality already built-in. You can use `Oak`.

```
import { Application, send } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";

const app = new Application();

app.use(async (context) => {
  await send(context, context.request.url.pathname, {
    root: `${Deno.cwd()}/client/dist/client`,
    index: "index.html",
  });
});

await app.listen({ port: 8080 });
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much for the middleware recommendation!